# Is there a "proper" way to load config files using ConfigParser? Or, is there an equivalent to logging.getLogger for config files?

Tags: python, configuration

I have a particularly large python project that has modules upon modules and classes that call other classes and so on. It's an organized mess.

I want to be able to just read the config file **once** and get/set key-value pairs out of it from any part of my program.

Right now, my setup looks like this: I have a module with these function

```
def initialize():
    config_file = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config_file_path = os.path.join(Path(__file__).resolve().parents[2], 'config.ini')

    try:
        config_file.read(config_file_path)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        raise FileNotFoundError
    else:
        return config_file, config_file_path


def get_config_data(section, key):
    config_file, _ = initialize()
    return config_file[section][key]


def set_config_data(section, key, value):
    config_file, config_file_path = initialize()
    config_file.set(section, key, str(value))

    with open(config_file_path, 'w') as f:
        config_file.write(f)
```

and whenever I need a config key-value pair, I just import it as `CFG` and use `CFG.get_config_data(KEY, VALUE)`. Which means I have to run `initialize` every single time I need something. I don't think it's ideal (or is it? I genuinely don't know)

Is there a "proper and standard" method for reading config files in large python projects? Something that I can just `import` and `get` in the beginning? Or there's nothing wrong with my set-up as it is?

Comment: Use a singleton: put your functions in a class, create a single instance of the class in the global scope, and import that instance wherever needed. This way you only need to call `initialize` once.

Comment: @jfaccioni neat. but there's really no built-in method for this? that's what i find strange

Comment: Pragmatically, is it noticeably slow to read the file again and again ? If so, do parse it only once and then store the result in a dict/singleton class/module top-level/whatever. Otherwise, if it is working, why change it ?